# Can sieve method prove ternary (three) prime Goldbach conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

Can sieve method prove ternary (three) prime Goldbach conjecture (Vinogradov Theorem) ?

I had done some research, I could not find any articles on this.
Can anyone provide some help on this ?

I assume that sieve method will be prove ternary (three) prime Goldbach conjecture (Vinogradov Theorem), because it can prove (1, 2) Chen's Theorem.

Comment: I posted a related question a while ago, which contains some links that might be relevant to you. Here it is: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/787042/131263.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the weak Goldbach conjecture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture
and was apparently solved by Harald Helfgott last year.  I don't know what his methods were.

Answer (score 1):

Terrence Tao [writes](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/heuristic-limitations-of-the-circle-method/) that it would be difficult to prove the weak Goldbach conjecture due to the [parity problem](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/06/05/open-question-the-parity-problem-in-sieve-theory/). Most of the progress has been made by a combination of the circle method and Fourier techniques.